# RDC from FF with async reset to FF with sync reset (no reset pin) - what is the design practice to solve this?

Tags: digital-logic, vlsi, asic, cdc

Given the below scenario, which is a reset-domain-crossing violation :

Can it be resolved using some reset synchronization strategy?

Is such design considered bad to begin with, i.e. need to avoid designing such paths?

NOTE: rstA and rst_B are different resets and are async to each other

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It Depends. It is re-synced on B side as long as reset is cleared properly and not too long. A better way is to use edge trigger for reset rather than state (D) then clock it. That may take 2 stages of FF's.

Comment: My problem is the use-case where reset A is getting asserted while reset B is not, that may cause a metastable value to propagate to the target FF.

Comment: If B is clocked, where is the metastable on output?